# Python Numpy 2-dimensional array iteration

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

Would like to build a list of indices into a 2 dimensional bool_ array, where True.

```
import numpy
arr = numpy.zeros((6,6), numpy.bool_)
arr[2,3] = True
arr[5,1] = True
results1 = [[(x,y) for (y,cell) in enumerate(arr[x].flat) if cell] for x in xrange(6)]
results2 = [(x,y) for (y,cell) in enumerate(arr[x].flat) if cell for x in xrange(6)]
```

results 1:

```
[[], [], [(2, 3)], [], [], [(5, 1)]]
```

results 2 is completely wrong

Goal:

```
[(2, 3),(5, 1)]
```

Any way to do this without flattening the list afterwards, or any better way to do this in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Here's an example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> arr = numpy.zeros((6,6), numpy.bool_)
>>> arr[2,3] = True
>>> arr[5,1] = True
>>> numpy.where(arr)
(array([2, 5]), array([3, 1]))
```

You can turn this back into an index like this:

```
>>> numpy.array(numpy.where(arr)).T
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 1]])
```

Comment: Oh dear, hadn't heard of that. zip(*numpy.where(arr)) is working nicely. I'll leave this open for awhile to hear if anyone else has alternatives.

Comment: `np.where()` with a single argument is equivalent to `np.nonzero()`. To transform to the OP's format: `np.transpose(np.nonzero(a))` that is equivalent to  `np.argwhere(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.zeros((6,6), np.bool_)
>>> arr[2,3] = True
>>> arr[5,1] = True
>>> np.argwhere(arr)
array([[2, 3],
       [5, 1]])
```